# Loading GeoDataFrame as QGIS vector layer without exporting to shapefile

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas, qgis-python-console, qgsvectorlayer

I'm using Python console in QGIS to manipulate geospatial data using GeoPandas. I want to load the output (GeoDataFrame) to the canvas as vector layer directly without exporting it to a file first. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: You mean temporary (memory) vector layer, right?

Comment: Right. But it solved by @ThomasG77 comment below. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following

```py
import geopandas

countries_gdf = geopandas.read_file("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp")

vl = QgsVectorLayer(countries_gdf.to_json(),"mygeojson","ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much :-)